# Reseated SSD and now it stopped functioning?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, motherboard

I wanted to re-seat my M.2 NVME SSD (240GB at 6GBPS from Drevo) the other direction so that I could apply the bracket supplied with my motherboard, as my attempts to put it on all failed at the time of building. It stopped showing a power light and didn't work, so I decided to put it back the way it originally functioned. It showed a power light! Nice, let's not mess with that anymore.... Or should I? It shows a power light but the BIOS does not recognize it, do NOT give me any answer that is already present on SE as it is not going to be what I am looking for. It is all the way in, clean connector, UEFI non-CSM, Windows PE doesn't show it, and it is not shown in bootable devices or SMART.

This is infuriating, my motherboard is the Asus TUF Mark II and my SSD is a Drevo 240GB 6GBPS M.2 SSD.

Comment: If you forced the device into a connector in the wrong direction, likely pins are broken and/or electrical parts destroyed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik However, the data pins on an M.2 SSD are symetrical but the power pins aren't and I can see the power light, so I don't think I damaged it.